# Exposed port 0 is not mapped. testcontainer c#

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, testcontainers

I have the following code

```cs
private readonly MsSqlTestcontainer _msSqlTestcontainer;

public DbSessionConnectionFactory()
{
    _msSqlTestcontainer = new TestcontainersBuilder<MsSqlTestcontainer>()
        .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest")
        .WithPortBinding(1433, 1433)
        .WithEnvironment("ACCEPT_EULA", "Y")
        .WithEnvironment("SA_PASSWORD", "Admin_12345")
        .Build();


}
public async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    await _msSqlTestcontainer.StartAsync();
}
```

A few days ago the `StartAsync` method was working without any error.

But now when I run the code I get the following exception:

> Port  '_msSqlTestcontainer.Port' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'    int {System.InvalidOperationException}

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Having the same problem here :) If you do figure it out, please post the solution here. (And I will do the same)

Comment: @Zvone The problem was solved by Andre Hofmeister aswner ;)

Comment: glad it worked for you! I actually pinged the very nice community of testcontainers on their slack and he responded to me so we troubleshooted for some time and then he replied with a fix here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following configuration:

```cs
.WithDatabase(new MsSqlTestcontainerConfiguration { Password = "Admin_12345" })
.WithExposedPort(1433)
.WithPortBinding(1433, true)
```

This was not a great moment, when I added an extension class to configure modules. The extension `WithDatabase` sets on the property `ContainerPort`. This property is not set by your configuration. That is why it cannot find the port.

You can skip the port configuration for modules. You can simplify your configuration to something like [this](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/blob/0215bbc263d7302f00f2eeaff9a7e5e8881cc893/tests/Testcontainers.Tests/Fixtures/Containers/Unix/Modules/Databases/MsSqlFixture.cs#L18-L20).

---

**Note:**

You should add `TrustServerCertificate=true;` into your `sqlserver` connection string.